# network manager missing from lubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking

I upgraded from lubuntu 13.10 to 14.04, network manager is missing from the tray after upgrading.

Tried to run nm-applet in terminal, with below reply:

"nm-applet-Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon".

Comment: Same thing for me on Ubuntu though